# NoClassDefFoundError hibernate criterion exporting jar

Tags: java, hibernate, export, manifest

I'm trying to export a java stand-alone class that uses hibernate. It's a really simple read/insert procedure. I'm stuck with this error

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>java -jar ImportDatiMeteo2.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criteri
on/Criterion
        at openplan.openergy.standalone.ImportDati.main(ImportDati.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

I was thinking it could be a manifest file problem so i checked. It seem ok to me.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/antlr-2.7.6rc1.jar lib/asm-attrs.jar lib/asm.jar 
 lib/c3p0-0.8.5.2.jar lib/cglib-2.1.3.jar lib/cleanimports.jar 
 lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar lib/concurrent-1.3.2.jar
 lib/connector.jar lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar lib/ehcache-1.1.jar lib/hibernate3.jar
 lib/jaas.jar lib/jacc-1_0-fr.jar lib/jaxen-1.1-beta-7.jar
 lib/jdbc2_0-stdext.jar lib/jgroups-2.2.7.jar lib/jta.jar lib/log4j-1.2.11.jar
 lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar lib/oscache-2.1.jar lib/proxool-0.8.3.jar
 lib/swarmcache-1.0rc2.jar lib/xerces-2.6.2.jar lib/xml-apis.jar  
Created-By: 1.6.0_21 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: openplan.openergy.standalone.ImportDati
```

In my Eclipse all the project work properly, does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: You need to repack hibernate jars into your `ImportDatiMeteo2.jar`

Comment: I have not enough details about what you want and what you did. Generally JAR is an archive, where all required `*.class` files located in compressed form. You can inspect jar content wiz ZIP archiver like 7-zip. You should have `org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.class` inside your jar in order java classloader can find it. Do you have this file inside your jar? If you haven't then your jar is not standalone and it requires hibernate jars be in classpath, set either in java command line or in system environment.

Comment: P.S. check your `Library handling` option in your eclipse export dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those libraries in classpath as you are running it from command line :

```
C:\> java -classpath <referenced-jars> -jar ImportDatiMeteo2.jar
```

> in myEclipse all the project work properly, does anyone know where the problem is ?

--> Because Eclipse will take care of your classpath and adding libraries in your classpath.

Comment: but if is specify it in the command line....what is manifest file for ? 

it's the first time i see this error...with other project i just used manifest file

Comment: @Medioman92 : I would give libraries in classpath as their path may get changed. Writing them in manifest which is in jar will be troublesome using your approach. I don't know whether we can give classpath in manifest. What I know is we can give main class in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `Library handling` option in your Eclipse export dialog. On my side it works fine with hibernate with `Extract required libraries into generated JAR` selected.